# ajax request after -load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some problems with Ajax and .load; 
I want to fire the ajax request under three circumstances. 
When a facility is chosen and when the preMonth/nextMonth was chosen.

My problem is that Ajax doesn't send the dates of the new month but the last active Month.

```
jQuery('main').on('click', '#terminstandorte select option, .nextMonth, .prevMonth', function(){

    //Some Code

    if (jQuery(this).get(0) == jQuery('.nextMonth').get(0)) {
        jQuery('#kalender').load('?' + jQuery(this).attr('value') + ' #thisMonth',function () {
            getFreeDates();
        });
    } else if (jQuery(this).get(0) == jQuery('.prevMonth').get(0)) {
        jQuery('#kalender').load('?' + jQuery(this).attr('value') + ' #thisMonth',function () {
            getFreeDates();
        });
    }

    var werk = parseInt(jQuery('#terminstandorte select option:selected').attr('value'));
    var firstDay = jQuery('.calDates .noDate:first').attr('id');
    var lastDay = jQuery('.calDates .noDate:last').attr('id');

    //Some Code again


    function getFreeDates() {
        //Hier werden alle freien Termine für den aktuellen Monat angezeigt
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: CENSORED,
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                request: request,
                werk: werk,
                firstDay: firstDay,
                lastDay: lastDay
            },
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            beforeSend: function () {
                // console.log(firstDay, lastDay);
                today = new Date(firstDay);
                console.log(today.getMonth()+1);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                freeDates = JSON.parse(data);
                freeDates.forEach(function (date) {
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Etwas lief schief');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

I tried to put the Ajax in a function, so that Ajax is called after the load, but the result is still the same.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `getMonth()` returning 0 = January. Maybe try to change it to `getMonth()+2`?

Comment: Thats not the Problem. 
When i go through the Months following will shown in return. 
(Month I see  ||  Month Ajax takes.) 
(4 || 4)
(5 || 4)
(6 || 5)
(5 || 6)
(4 || 5)

Comment: Don't you need to pass the value of `werk` `firstday` `lastday` as the function parameter as they aren't global?